# Help identifying XEON processor

Tags: intel, xeon, central-processing-unit

I have an old server with an **Intel XEON Processor**.  I have been trying to identify which exact version it is with no luck.  I tried various tools but all they do is give you some info about the processor with no actual version (processor number).

Here is what I know about it so far:

**Clock Speed 3.00 GHz**

The motherboard is an **Intel 5000P Chipset** so I know it should be a **Intel Xeon 5000** series but maybe not.

It is a dual core hyperthreaded (so it shows up as 4 cores on Task Manager)

It has **2MB** level 2 Cache

It supports **Intel Hardware Virtulization**

I have looked though the Intel website and I just can't find a processor that has the exact same specs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a Xeon 5050. The cache size is 2x2MB ( i suspect whatever tool reported that 2MB was reporting per core) not 4MB as indicated on the Intel site [Intel® Xeon® Processor 5050 | intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27210). It's not hard to figure this out. The socket for 5000P is LGA 771. You now go to [List of Intel Xeon microprocessors | en.wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors) search for 3000 MHz and 3 GHz and look for LGA 771 matches with a low amount of cache. That's then 5050 or 5160 where the latter does not support HT [Intel® Xeon® Processor 5160 | intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27219)

Comment: That’s not concrete evidence. You are not then accounting for a few factors. It’s always best to use something that proves it completely. As the next answer nicely points out CPU-Z or on Linux cat /proc/cpuinfo although I do appreciate in 99% of cases your answer gives a strong indication :)

Comment: Holy necromancy, Batman! Blast from the past, if there ever was one. Do note the question includes "I tried various tools but all they do is give you some info about the processor with no actual version (processor number)" thus I tried to give an idea on how to id something based on characteristics and not tools. Today the same would work: socket (or generation), threads/core, gigahertz, vPro support together identifies an Intel CPU. Admittedly: the various CPU info tools work a lot better now.

Answer (score 9):

Under Windows you might want to try [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).  Under linux, you can try `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [bootable version of Intel's processor identification tool](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?ProductID=1881&DwnldID=7840&lang=eng&iid=dc_rss)?

This tool runs on bare metal, and it may help to identify the CPU if your operating system is somehow getting in the way.

Comment: I will give it a try to verify the answer below, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check in BIOS? Normaly you'll have the exact CPU model in there.